# Is it possible to perform an MDA Transformation via C#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect, mda

I'm using the Enterprise Architect 10.0.1006 to create "Platform Specific Models" (PSM) from an "Platform Independent Model" (PIM). The PIM is an common codel which declares datatypes with a generic description. You can transform this common model to a specific Model (Java, C++, Php and so on).

But to do so, I have to open the project and perform the "Transform Current Package" Tab on every package I want to transform.

It works well but I want to know, if it's possible to write an automatic script in C# to perform this Task. 
There is a COM to change nearly everything in your projectbrowser. I can access every diagram, element or package through this COM. But I didn't find any method to transform the model.

My Question is: **Can I execute this tranfsormation with an automated script using C#?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Look at the Object Model API, Project::TransformPackage().

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the Hint I needed.